# Which events are raised when a form is showned after it was hiding (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, forms

In my vb.net project, I navigate between forms.
I have a main form in which I can display new forms and modify some information in them.

When I closed these new forms, the main form, previously hidden by using the `form.hide()` method, is displayed by the `form.show()` method and should consider these modifications.

In order to do that I need to know which event(s) is(are) raised when a form is shown by the form.show() method.

I already try to use the `form.show` event but it is only raised when the form is firstly showned at the start.

Comment: Are you talking about the events or about the naviguation between forms

Comment: By "previously hidden" do you mean that it was closed, or that you hid it in some other way?

Comment: Both. What are the other events and navigation you have tried. This will narrow down how to help

Comment: @JustinRyan  no it was just hidden using the form.hide() method

Comment: @Sam I already tried the `form.load` event and I seen also the `form.activated` event but I don't understand when it is raised

Comment: The VisibleChanged event fires.

Comment: Ok I try this right now

Comment: The `load` event will get raised when the form gets loaded for the first time. If it gets closed the load will be run again next time it is opened. `activated` will be any time it has been activated so will get called if you hide it and then show it and on first load as well

Comment: @Sam Thank you for these explanations but I tried with the VisibleChanged event and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching between `.Hide()` and `.Show()` the `VisibleChanged` event is raised.

If you want a more robust method (albeit more code), you can overload your form's `Show` method.

```
Public Overloads Sub Show(Optional ByVal getData As Boolean = False)
    If getData Then
        'get data from other form
    End If

    MyBase.Show()
End Sub
```

Your form will act normally, except in the case where you call it from your secondary forms, in which case your extra code is called, like so:

```
myMainForm.Show(True)
```

This method would be preferred in cases where you might be show/hide-ing the form, but do not want your extra code to be called every time.